# Enter PSSession with Variable for ComputerName

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to enter a PSSession using `-Computername $Server` which was previously defined, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have tried single, double, and no quotes around the variable at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
$Servers = Import-Csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\DNS.csv"
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$myCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", $secpass)

foreach ($Object in $Servers) {
    $Server = $Object.Name

    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "$Server" -Credential $myCred
    sl HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters}
    Exit-PSSession
}
```

[image]

Comment: No quotes or double quotes should be fine, no substitution is performed with single quotes so they won't work here. See [about_quoting_rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for more info on this. Have you [enabled remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx) on the servers you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes, remoting is enabled on all servers

Answer (score 1):

We use enter pssession for creating an interactive session with the remote computer.

In your case, you do not need to have an interaction with the remote system. You just need to fetch the details from the remote systems which are present in the csv file.

So, Instead of this:

```
foreach($Object in $Servers) {

$Server = $Object.Name

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "$Server" -Credential $myCred

    sl HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters

        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters}

Exit-PSSession

}
```

Do This:

```
foreach($Object in $Servers) 
{
$Server = $Object.Name
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters} -Credential $myCred
}
```

Note: I believe you have enabled PSRemoting and have edited trusted hosts.

Comment: This is running now, but it is still returning the information from my local registry instead of remote.. Any idea why?

Comment: NO its not. You can check the value coming in $Server. Let me modify one more time.

Comment: @4c74356b41: What i meant is that for getting the information from the remote system, he don't need to create an interactive PSSession. A non-interactive remote session is enough,

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, it now shows PSComputerName in a "PS Table" format, but under property it is still pulling from the local machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `ComputerName` param of `Invoke-Command` will accept an array of servers so you can do away with the foreach loop entirely and simplify your code to:

```
$Servers = Import-Csv "C:\Users\username\Desktop\DNS.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$myCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", $secpass)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock {Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters} -Credential $myCred
```

Comment: This sounds easier. However, it is still pulling from the local machine instead of the remote.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, not sure how you're getting that result. Try changing the Path to `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName` as this contains the Computers Name which will double check that you are indeed getting what you think.